# mapreduce in couchDB and getting the MAX result after mapreduce

Tags: mapreduce, max, couchdb

I am a beginner to couchDB.
I have data as below:

```
one:[{
     "name":abc,
     "value":1
}, 
{    
     "name":efg,
     "value":1
},
{    
     "name":abc,
     "value":1
},
```

I would like to get the count of similar keys and get the maximum.
e.g. in my case "abc" is twice. so the maximum(reduce function) should return 
result: `{"name":abc,value:2}`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this design document:

```
{
  "_id":"_design/company",
  "views":
  {
    "abc_customers": {
      "map": "function(doc) { if (doc.name == 'abc') emit(doc.name,doc.value) }",
      "reduce" : "_count"
    },
    "efg_customers": {
      "map": "function(doc) { if (doc.name == 'efg') emit(doc.name,doc.value) }",
      "reduce" : "_count"
    }
  }
}
```

See [this one](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions) for a comparison of `_count` and `_sum`. Possibly you need `_count`.

By the above CouchDB design document, you will get count for each `doc.name` of `abc`, `efg`, ... and then you can do a search for max/min of counts.